# truepush.com push-notification icon with RSS

Tags: xml, push-notification, rss

I'm using the push-notification service from [truepush.com](https://truepush.com) with RSS-feed.

I read the tutorial for using [push-notification](https://www.truepush.com/blog/rss-to-push-notifications/) and setup a XML file.
Everything works fine, I get `title`, `description` and the `thumbnail` in my push notification. It is possible to set the default website icon in the RSS-feed dashboard for every push notification, but I want to have the `<item>` thumbnail shown as `icon` so it gets also displayed on desktop devices. Following the tutorial it is possible to define an `icon` with `Rss->channel->item->icon` or `Rss->channel->image`. I tried both. If I use `Rss->channel->item->icon`, the RSS-feed does not get recognized because `<icon>` is not a valid `<item>` in RSS. I also tried `Rss->channel->image` but no icon gets displayed. Here is my current [XML-file](https://mediabookdb.de/feed/mediabooks.xml).

Answer (score 0):

So in RSS feed to add your own icon you have to place the icon as `rss->channel->image->url` and your icon url will be

`<image>
    <url>Your Icon URL</url>
 </image>`

This is a way to add icon image to the feed and Truepush notifications

Please try adding this to the feed and see if the icon in the notifications changes.